# How can I line up a select list on my DIV?

Tags: css

I have this code

```
 <div id="one">
  <a href="#" id="test1" >
    <button title="test1">test1</button>
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="test1" >
    <button title="test1">test1</button>
  </a>
  <div id="two" style="background-color: red;">
  <form action="/adminTest" method="post"><select id="SelectedCode" name="SelectedCode">
<option value="1">1 page</option>
<option value="2">2 pages</option>
</select>    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>  
    </div> 
</div>
```

I would like my select dropdown to appear to the right of the button but it appears below. Is there an easy way to make it appear the way I would like?

Comment: A a href around a button? Odd.

Comment: Why on earth do you have a hyperlink around a button?

Comment: You've updated your HTML since your question was first posted. That's fine, but I'm just going to point out that in your actual page, you should not have duplicate `id`s. Use a `class` instead.

Comment: 1) do you really need a href arround buttons? and 2) float the links to left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add `display: inline;` to your form element via CSS.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/PWuCm/1/).

Answer (score 2):

You could `float: left` your link:

http://jsfiddle.net/PWuCm/3/

```
#test1 {
    float: left
}
```

Updated with your new HTML.. http://jsfiddle.net/PWuCm/4/

As per my comment on your question, I changed the `id`s to a `class`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to place that test1 button inside the form.